# Alinear texto con su imagen

Tags: css, div

Hola compañeros Tengo un texto al lado de una imagen que es un formulario (botón de compra)
como hago para que el texto me quede al lado izquierdo de la imagen en el centro como esta [image: Así como esta]
[image: así es como me queda]

He usado inline entre otras pero no me sale.

A continuación adjunto código:

```css
/*CONTENIDO DEL CUERPO DONDE VA IMAGENES Y PRODUCTOS*/

.cajapadre {
  text-align: center;
  /* Una caja al lado de la otra importante padre*/
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.caja4hijo {
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 225px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* inline-block una caja al lado d ela otra importante hoja */
  /*float: left;*/
  /*para quedar a la misma altura, puedo usar blick y float left y darle altura al la caja titulo caja imagen y cajaboton */
}

.caja3hijo {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 302px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* una caja al lado d ela otra importante hoja */
}

.caja2hijo {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* una caja al lado d ela otra importante hoja */
}


/*.espacio-art {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
}*/

.titulo-art {
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #C42427;
  background: #9AB01E;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.imagen-art {
  height: 280px;
}

.imagen-ofer {
  height: 320px;
}

.separador {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="cajapadre">
    <!--------contiene 4 cajas--------->
    <div class="caja4hijo">
      <div class="titulo-art espacio-art">3M™ Littmann® Lightweight</div>

      <div class="imagen-art espacio-art">
        <a class="picfancy" href="img/art-varios/olivas.jpg" title="3M™ Littmann® Lightweight "><img src="img/art-varios/olivas.jpg" width="133" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="boton-art espacio-art">
        <!-----icono de comprar---->
        <div>
          Gris

          <form id="frm_botonePayco" name="frm_botonePayco" method="post" action="https://secure.payco.co/checkout.php">
            <img src="img/boton/comprar.jpg" width="126" alt="" />
          </form>
        </div>
        <div>
          Negro

          <form id="frm_botonePayco" name="frm_botonePayco" method="post" action="https://secure.payco.co/checkout.php">
            <img src="img/boton/comprar.jpg" width="126" alt="" />
          </form>
        </div>



        <!-----icono de comprar---->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja4hijo">
      <div class="titulo-art espacio-art">3M™ Littmann® Select</div>

      <div class="imagen-art espacio-art">
        <a class="picfancy" href="img/art-varios/caucho-post-classic.jpg" title="3M™ Littmann® Select"><img src="img/art-varios/caucho-post-classic.jpg" width="133" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="boton-art espacio-art">
        <!-----icono de comprar---->

        <!-----icono de comprar---->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja4hijo">
      <div class="titulo-art espacio-art">3M™ Littmann® Pediatrico</div>

      <div class="imagen-art espacio-art">
        <a class="picfancy" href="img/art-varios/kit-liviano.jpg" title="3M™ Littmann® Pediatrico"><img src="img/art-varios/kit-liviano.jpg" width="133" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="boton-art espacio-art">
        <!-----icono de comprar---->

        <!-----icono de comprar---->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="caja4hijo">
      <div class="titulo-art espacio-art">3M™ Littmann® Pediatrico Edición Especial</div>

      <div class="imagen-art espacio-art">
        <a class="picfancy" href="img/art-varios/kit-classicii.jpg" title="3M™ Littmann® Pediatrico Edición Especial"><img src="img/art-varios/kit-classicii.jpg" width="133" alt="" /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="boton-art espacio-art">
        <!-----icono de comprar---->

        <!-----icono de comprar---->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Gracias amigos

Comment: Daniel, viendo tu código, solo esta el "Gris" y el "Negro" en la primera tabla, no en la segunda. Por casualidad adjuntaste el código de la segunda tabla. Se que esta, pero no están los elementos donde dice "Comprar". Por favor, puedes compartir dicho código para poder dar solución?

Comment: Donde debe ir el boton, es un formulario no lo puse completo porque contiene datos sensibles, pero en resumen es un formulario con una imagen de boton de compra.

Comment: @Daniel, no olvides marcar la respuesta que consideres correcta por favor. Te invito a [hacer el tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que sepas cómo funciona el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no logre captar bien como lo tenias en el real, preferí colocarte del mismo modo.

```
<div class="boton-art espacio-art">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Gris
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <!-----icono de comprar---->
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    Negro
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <!-----icono de comprar---->
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

A pesar que es un poco mas de trabajo, pero en una tabla puedes manipular mejor el manejo de lo que hablabas. Y de esta forma lo resuelves rápido.

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Veo que eliminaste una respuesta muy parecida. En caso no lo sepas, **puedes editar una respuesta eliminada**. Una vez que la editas, le das click en *recuperar* para restaurarla. Saludos.

Comment: No quería usar tablas pero ahora es la solución mas radical. gracias

Answer (score 0):

No sé que etiqueta usas para mostrar el texto, por eso, te recomiendo hacer el text `inline-block`:

```css
.espacio-art {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto; /* Solo para centrar aquí */
  width: 200px;
}

p {
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button {
  background-color: orangered;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 14px;
}
```

```html
<article class="espacio-art">
  <p>Negro</p>
  <button>Comprar</button>
</article>
```

Otra forma es usando Flexbox definiendo una orientación horiztonal:

```css
.espacio-art {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

button {
  background-color: orangered;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 14px;
}
```

```html
<article class="espacio-art">
  <p>Gris</p>
  <button>Comprar</button>
</article>
```

En este caso no es necesario usar `inline-block` en los hijos, porque cuando se usa `display: flex` los hijos son posicionados horizontalmente, sin importar qué tipo de display tengan.

Comment: El formulario con su boton ya este hecho, es mas largo el codigo no lo puse todo porque contiene datos sensibles. lo que dese es que el texo, gris o negro este el lado izquierdo, alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: @Daniel perdón, entendí justamente lo contrario. He actualizado mi respuesta.